# Python Command line argument and SQlite3 access

Tags: python, sqlite, command-line-arguments

I am trying to understand how to write a script that would first take a directory name as a command line argument, then discovers all files in the associated directory subtree. It stores the information in a Sqlite3 database, in a table named files containing 3 fields: (ext, path, fname), which represent the file extension (.cpp, .doc, etc.), the full path name of the directory (only) the file resides in, and the name of the file (e.g., foo.cpp).

The name of the SQLite database file should be the second command-line argument ().

This is a sample command line:

```
python readfiles.py Stuff filesdb
```

Here is a sample of some of the entries in files:

```
(u'ppt', u'Stuff/ACCU', u'ACCU-Templates.ppt')
(u'cpp', u'Stuff/ACCU/code/C01', u'Auto_ptr.cpp')
(u'cpp', u'Stuff/ACCU/code/C01', u'Autoexcp.cpp')
(u'cpp', u'Stuff/ACCU/code/C01', u'BadException.cpp')
(u'cpp', u'Stuff/ACCU/code/C01', u'Basexcpt.cpp')
(u'cpp', u'Stuff/ACCU/code/C01', u'Cleanup.cpp')
```

I am not very familiar with accessing databases in the first place and just need some suggestions on best ways this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

To get the command line arguments you can use the `sys.argv` list. For your example command invocation:

```
import sys

root = sys.argv[1]
db_name = sys.argv[2]
```

Executing that results in `root` being set to `'Stuff'` and `db_name` set to `'filesdb'`.

The other part of your question can be solved using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to traverse the file system.

```
import os
import os.path
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('create table if not exists files (ext text, path text, fname text)')

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
        for filename in filenames:
            ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].replace('.', '')
            cursor.execute('insert into files (ext, path, fname) values (?, ?, ?)', (ext, dirpath, filename))
```

A potential performance improvement can be gained by using [`cursor.executemany()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.executemany) instead of a query per file. To do that you would build up a list of tuples containing `(ext, dirpath, filename)` and pass that to `executemany()`.